# How can I read and process 100 bytes at a time from a large CSV file?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, parsing, sys

The below csv is only a snippet of my main data file.

**customer.csv**

```
customer_id,order_id,number_of_items
10,4736,9
5,3049,1
1,4689,3
6,4114,9
1,4524,15
2,3727,16
3,3507,7
7,3988,3
5,4993,16
6,1945,4
7,3081,7
3,3707,2
5,1739,12
9,4167,17
7,3242,12
2,3109,10
10,2197,20
10,3528,13
8,4917,2
5,1713,19
8,4224,4
7,2160,2
10,2044,19
10,2956,8
3,3906,2
5,2288,16
7,1854,20
7,4404,2
9,1622,2
7,3685,2
10,2755,10
3,3390,10
6,1424,6
3,2127,15
4,1221,15
9,2994,14
1,1413,13
7,2771,7
3,4579,13
10,2208,4
```

**CURRENTLY ALL I HAVE**

```
import os
os.path.getsize("customer.csv") # outputs, 424 bytes
```

**HOW I THINK I NEED TO PROCEED**

I think I need to do something with open csv and read bytes? Then look at each row bit wise?

Please note, I am not looking specifically for someone to just give me an answer on how to do this (although that would be appreciated). Therefore, if someone could just point me in the right direction or give me some topics to look into that would be great. Side note, I know I am supposed to use encoding and decoding somewhere for this task.

Comment: Do you want parse the csv file? There's `csv` module in Python standard library for that - https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: Correct. I am aware of the csv module, but I’m not sure how to specifically read in only 100 bytes while checking to see if the necessary byte information is there for each line. The purpose of parsing the CSV is to build a dictionary of unique customer id’s (keys) and the average number of items they purchased (value).

Comment: I don't understand, why do you need to read only 100 bytes at a time? This sounds like the X-Y problem to me...

Comment: I'm not sure either..After looking at @AndrejKesely answer and running `print(sys.getsizeof(data))` 56 bytes are outputted. Is this the size of each line? Or the data set as a whole? The assignment I’m working on verbatim says:                     Storage space is important for this assignment; thus, combine above numbers (using bit operations) into a single integer per customer that can be disassembled into the numbers above later on. Please provide functions to encode and decode values.

Comment: @TonyPendleton `sys.getsizeof` returns the size of the object you pass to it in bytes (but not the objects *it* has references to, i.e. it doesn't recursively give you the total size of an object graph). So `data` is a `csv.DictReader` object, which requires 56 bytes. This is neither the size of each line or the data set as a whole. Honestly, `sys.getsizeof` isn't going to be useful to you here.

Answer (score 0):

This script will use the `csv` to load the data from `customer.csv` and compute the average using the builtin `statistics` module:

```
import csv
from statistics import mean

with open('customer.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    data = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

    # group the customers by customer_id
    customers = {}
    for order in data:
        customers.setdefault(order['customer_id'], []).append(int(order['number_of_items']))

    # print the `average`:
    print('{:<15} {}'.format('customer_id', 'average'))
    for k, v in customers.items():
        print('{:<15} {:.2f}'.format(k, mean(v)))
```

Prints:

```
customer_id     average
10              11.86
5               12.80
1               10.33
6               6.33
2               13.00
3               8.17
7               6.88
9               11.00
8               3.00
4               15.00
```